# Do Hindu scriptures prescribe how dead bodies can be preserved for centuries?

Tags: ramanujacharya

This question was prompted by Vaishnavite claims that the body of Ramanuja is preserved at Srirangam temple even today.

http://www.holydham.com/sri-ramanujacharya/

"His physical body is preserved even today in a sitting posture in the Sannidhi (Sanctum Sanctorum).Yearly twice the body is applied Pachai Karpuram (Camphor) and Kumkum (Vermillon)."