# Do scriptures allow embalmmemt as an alternative to dispose of Hindu dead bodies?

Tags: practice

I believe both cremation and burial are allowed in Hinduism.  Is there any mention of preserving corpses to be viewable for posterity or at least for a long time?  There is only one claim as far as I know of embalming a Hindu religious figure - Ramanuja.

Comment: You have already asked same question. [Do Hindu scriptures prescribe how dead bodies can be preserved for centuries?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22479/3500)

Comment: This is not a duplicate - it asks if it is allowed in Hindu scripture- the other question is about techniques of embalmment.

Comment: Basically you are asking same question bit differently.

Comment: If it is not allowed, why would a scripture talk about it  and give methods to do it? This is same as that question.

Comment: Hindu apologists claim there is lot of science in Hindu scripture.  The other question may be considered a question on "HIndu science".  This is a real Hindu practice question.